# not able to get the search button with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrap articles from [this](https://www.theaustralian.com.au/) website. I manage to do the login part but when I try to click on the search button and send the values I got a timeout error. I try running the selenium with **start-maximize** option and I noticed the page don't seem to load.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search__input"]')))
input_text = elem.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="search__input"]').click()
input_text.send_keys("Anthony Albanese")
print(input_text.get_attribute('value'))
```

I have tried to use the `get_attribute('innerHtml')` and I got the search button HTML but I have to send the keys so it does not seems to be of any use. This is the error that I got
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO1Ut.png). What should I do to send in the search terms?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 elements on that page matching `//*[@id="search__input"]` XPath locator, while you need the second one.
You have to use unique locator.
This should work better:

```py
text_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='header__search']//*[@id='search__input']")))
text_input.click()
text_input.send_keys("Anthony Albanese")
```

This can also be done with CSS Selectors. They are shorter in this case:

```py
text_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".header__search #search__input")))
text_input.click()
text_input.send_keys("Anthony Albanese")
```

**UPD**
This is the code I used, exactly accordingly to what I wrote before:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://www.theaustralian.com.au/"
driver.get(url)
text_input = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".header__search #search__input")))
text_input.click()
text_input.send_keys("Anthony Albanese")
```

The web page after the code above looks as following:
[image]

And if you add an `Enter` click to the search input as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://www.theaustralian.com.au/"
driver.get(url)
text_input = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".header__search #search__input")))
text_input.click()
text_input.send_keys("Anthony Albanese" + Keys.ENTER)
```

the web page will finally become as following

[image]

Comment: I got the same timeout exception with both xpath and css_selector

Comment: I have to login first so my code is first logging in. Dont know why im getting timeout.sorry i cant shars the email n password

Comment: Well, I made my code accordingly to what you shared and it works perfect. Logging in is not there...